# Conversion of MVC 2 project in VS2008 to VS 2010.. failure on one project.. Project type wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

So I'm trying to take a VS2008 MVC1 project to MVC3.

Here are the steps I'm trying to do.

1. Use conversion to to convert vs2008 mvc1 to vs 2008 mvc2 (success)
      Tool: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx
2. Open vs2008 sln in vs2010 to convert (failed on my main app project)
3. Convert from .Net3.5 to .Net 4.0
4. Use tool to covert to MVC3

On step two, it fails on my main project, and then will not open the project with the error.

```
 The Project <project path> cannot be opened

 The project type is not supported by this installation
```

I found some StackOverflow posts abotu similar issue with RC1 and RC2, but installaed my MVC2 from the webplatform installer and so it should eb the latest, not the RC.

I assume this line is my problme, anyone know how to fix it?

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

I tried posting my csproj, but it excedded the max lines.. if there is a part neede to diagnose this just let me know.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it both ways and got the same result.

I did figure it out, here's what was going on. Be aware that steps 1 and 3 are probably all that's needed to fix it, but I'm including step two, both for clarity of my debugging process and completeness in case it's required and my assumptions are false.

1. Even though MVC# was installed, and showed as installed in the Add removed programs, MVC 3 was not showing up as a reference. I unininstalled, reinstalled and rebooted and it started showing up.
2. I had to modify the project Type Guids in he CSPROJ file, first I deleted them one at a time till the Main app project was able to load, then I recovnerted. All projects except the main one worked, but it didnt' convert. It did not covnert becuase of an unrecognized project Type Guid.

Becasue it didnt convert I got this error:

**The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll' or from assembly 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\1.0.**

Note the Coverted did not throw and error, it merely logged that the project did not get convereted. You have to look at the logs carefully to notice. 
Luckily you can run the converter on the same soloution  multiple times. that's how I noticed this.

1. I had to modify the Project Type guids again, because of the unrecognized type guid again. I just created a new MVC3 project and  edited the CSPROJ to get the correct type guids.

   {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

Note: this is what the guids already looked like, but I copied them from an existing good project and pasted them in the file and it started working, my best guess is there was an invisible character put in there by the conversion process.

After this I reconverted and it worked perfectly, and the errors went away.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use the following migration path <sup>*</sup>:

1. Ensure that I have [ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491) installed
2. Open the ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project in Visual Studio 2010
3. The migration wizard kicks in and asks me if I want to convert to .NET 4.0 and I say *Yes*

   [image]
4. Make sure that the System.Web.Mvc assembly referenced in my project is V2.0.0.0. If it is still the old I remove it and add the correct version

At this stage I ensure that I have a working ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application and close Visual Studio.

There is one final step left. For it, depending on my mood, I do one of the following:

- Do the migration manually by following the [upgrade guide](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading)
- Use the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx)

<sup>* To answer this question I did the previous steps on a real ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project and it was successfully upgraded to ASP.NET MVC 3</sup>

Comment: I tried it yoru way and got the exact same results... but I did finaly figure it out I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: Upvoted becasue your answer was accurate and helpful, even if it did not solve the issue I was having.